# Using MySQL FIELD Function within Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to replicate the following in Sequelize. Unfortunately, I have not been able to replicate it completely and not enough to actually get it to work. I need to `ORDER BY FIELD`.

**Working Query**

> SELECT * FROM invoices ORDER BY FIELD(invoice_status_key, 'unpaid',
>   'overdue', 'open', 'paid') ASC;

Here is the code that I have that is close but not exact and not working:

> Invoice.findAll({ order: [ [sequelize.fn('FIELD',
>   ['invoice_status_key', 'open', 'unpaid', 'overdue', 'paid']), 'ASC']
>   ], logging: console.log });

This code produces the following query:

> SELECT `id`, `company_id`, `customer_id`, `job_id`,
>   `invoice_status_key`, `identifier`, `subtotal`, `tax`, `shipping`,
>   `total`, `summary`, `due_at`, `paid_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
>   FROM `invoices` AS `Invoice` ORDER BY FIELD('invoice_status_key',
>   'open', 'unpaid', 'overdue', 'paid') ASC;

Presumably what is wrong is the field `invoice_status_key` is being quoted inside the function while the function expects it to NOT be quoted. I have tried numerous ways and this is the closest that I have gotten but unfortunately it does not yield the results in the correct order.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use a literal and raw query to accomplish what I was after.

> let invoices = await Invoice.findAll({
>       order: [
>         sequelize.literal("FIELD(invoice_status_key, 'open', 'unpaid', 'overdue', 'paid') ASC")]
>       ] });

Which produced the end result as expected.